# How can I compare two source code files/ ast trees?

Tags: parsing, go, compare, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm generating some source code using the [templates](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) package( is there a better method? )and part of the testing I need to check if the output matches the expected source code.

- I tried a string comparison but it fails due the extra spaces / new lines generated by the templates package. I've also tried [format.Source](https://golang.org/pkg/go/format/) with not success. ( FAIL)
- I tried to parse the ast of the both sources (see bellow) but the ast doesn't match either even if the code is basically same except the new lines / spaces. (FAIL)

  package main

  ```
  import (
      "fmt"
      "go/parser"
      "go/token"
      "reflect"
  )

  func main() {
      stub1 := `package main
       func myfunc(s string) error {
          return nil  
      }`
      stub2 := `package main

       func myfunc(s string) error {

          return nil

      }`
      fset := token.NewFileSet()
      r1, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "", stub1, parser.AllErrors)
      if err != nil {
          panic(err)
      }
      fset = token.NewFileSet()
      r2, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "", stub2, parser.AllErrors)
      if err != nil {
          panic(err)
      }
      if !reflect.DeepEqual(r1, r2) {
          fmt.Printf("e %v, r %s, ", r1, r2)
      }
  }
  ```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/HABfWtsLuf)

Comment: Do you want to compare arbitrary trees, or just go trees that you have parsed?

Comment: Just go source code/trees, thus the go tag

Comment: https://www.diffchecker.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was easier than I thought. All I had to do was to remove the empty new lines(after formatting). Below is the code.

```
    package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "go/format"
        "strings"
    )

    func main() {
        a, err := fmtSource(stub1)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        b, err := fmtSource(stub2)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        if a != b {
            fmt.Printf("a %v, \n b %v", a, b)
        }
    }

func fmtSource(source string) (string, error) {
    if !strings.Contains(source, "package") {
        source = "package main\n" + source
    }
    b, err := format.Source([]byte(source))
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    // cleanLine replaces double space with one space
    cleanLine := func(s string)string{
        sa := strings.Fields(s)
        return strings.Join(sa, " ")
    }
    lines := strings.Split(string(b), "\n")
    n := 0
    var startLn *int
    for _, line := range lines {
        if line != "" {
            line = cleanLine(line)
            lines[n] = line
            if startLn == nil {
                x := n
                startLn = &x
            }
            n++
        }
    }
    lines = lines[*startLn:n]
    // Add final "" entry to get trailing newline from Join.
    if n > 0 && lines[n-1] != "" {
        lines = append(lines, "")
    }


    // Make it pretty 
    b, err = format.Source([]byte(strings.Join(lines, "\n")))
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return string(b), nil
}
```

Comment: Honestly, i think a better approach would've been to add a `hashCode` method to every AST node, then to match them you just check if both AST have the same hashCode

Answer (score 8):

Well, one simple way to achieve this is to use the `go/printer` library, that gives you better control of output formatting, and is basically like running `gofmt` on the source, normalizing both trees:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
    "go/printer"
    //"reflect"
    "bytes"
)

func main() {
    stub1 := `package main
     func myfunc(s string) error {
        return nil  
    }`
    stub2 := `package main

     func myfunc(s string) error {

        return nil

    }`

    fset1 := token.NewFileSet()
    r1, err := parser.ParseFile(fset1, "", stub1, parser.AllErrors)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fset2 := token.NewFileSet()
    r2, err := parser.ParseFile(fset1, "", stub2, parser.AllErrors)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // we create two output buffers for each source tree
    out1 := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    out2 := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)

    // we use the same printer config for both
    conf := &printer.Config{Mode: printer.TabIndent | printer.UseSpaces, Tabwidth: 8}

    // print to both outputs
    if err := conf.Fprint(out1, fset1, r1); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := conf.Fprint(out2, fset2, r2); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }


    // they should be identical!
    if string(out1.Bytes()) != string(out2.Bytes()) {
        panic(string(out1.Bytes()) +"\n" + string(out2.Bytes()))
    } else {
        fmt.Println("A-OKAY!")
    }
}
```

Of course this code needs to be refactored to not look as stupid. Another approach is instead of using DeepEqual, create a tree comparison function yourself, that skips irrelevant nodes.

Comment: The comparison function may not be trivial so I'm trying to avoid that. printer seems to fail on more "complex" structures http://play.golang.org/p/I9cAVEYLAm

Comment: @mihai maybe traverse the tree and filter it, then use DeepEqual?

Comment: Any idea how exactly can I filter the irrelevant nodes? I've tried to remove the nil nodes assuming they represent the new lines / spaces but it doesn't seem to be the case. play.golang.org/p/JVVpKIzela

Comment: A nit: `bytes.Buffer` has a `String()` method, so you don't need all those conversions.